# How to change server time?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I need to change server time from asp.net page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible or not, it's a bad idea.  And the only way I can think of allowing this is if the user account the app pool is executing under has some serious access rights to the machine; which is also a very bad idea.

Servers should be sync'd with a time server.  This is normally controlled at the OS level.

All sorts of funky things can happen once one server in a mix gets out of an acceptable date range.

Which leads us to the question: Why?

---

**UPDATE**

You could pinvoke SetSystemTime.  This will require the user the app pool is running under to have the SeSystemTimePrivilege.  More information and an example of pinvoking here: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/274594-how-set-system-date-c

Again, this is a Bad Idea(tm).

Comment: +1, Plus, you will need elevated privileges for the asp.net apppool account. Bad idea if I've ever seen one.

Comment: Kerberos implementations will fail if times get out of sync. This is but one example of a "funky thing"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not what you asked and does not change the server time, only changes the time from the perspective of the asp.net page. If the time difference is a constant then this code might be your friend!

This example adds 1 hour from now...

```
var today = DateTime.Now; 
var duration = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0); 
var answer = today.Add(duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thread explaining how to change systemtime

[I can't get SetSystemTime to work in Windows Vista using C# with Interop (P/Invoke)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486125/i-cant-get-setsystemtime-to-work-in-windows-vista-using-c-with-interop-p-invok)

You will need elevation to get this to work.